# GCC default integer/floating arithmetic behavior

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I have a set of very long equations that I originally wrote targeting MATLAB. Now, I have to port it to embedded C for my controller.

C and C++ default behavior when one writes `double a = 1/3;` is to return 0, since it is parsed as integer arithmetic. I wonder if there is a way to turn off this behavior, so that I don't need to append .0 to every single constant number along the equations.

For example, the following is a relatively short one:

```
eq = (121.0/16.0*pow(d,4)*pow(r,2)*pow(x,10)+2*pow(r,2)*pow(11.0/6.0,3)*pow(d,4)*pow(x,10) + pow(r,2)*pow(11.0/6.0,6)*pow(d,6)*pow(x,18) + pow(r,2)*pow(d,2)*pow(x,2) - pow(jmax,2));
```

My target is a ARM computer, so I am using Linaro GCC.

Edit:

As it turns out, changing GCC behavior was a huge no-no.
Solved this using regular expressions, thanks to @Matteo Italia.
Ended up writing a small Qt-based solution for replacing ^ as power symbols and to add trailing `.0` to literal numbers, available here:
https://github.com/pauloasherring/MATEquationToC
If you are to use it, do it at your own risk :)

Comment: In `pow(d,4)`, the `4` will get converted to a `double` by the function call, but in an expression such as `1/3` you need to change the type of at least one of the operands to `double`. For example: `1./3`, `1/3.`, `(double)1/3` or `1/(double)3` will all evaluate to 0.333333....

Comment: Which ARM? If it's one of the smaller Cortex M, then you can tell MATLAP to get lost, because they don't come with a FPU.

Comment: @Lundin, it is a Cortex A-8, in a Beaglebone Black.

Comment: you can tack on an F or D rather than .0 and go after all constants not just ones without any decimal points...if/when you have to do this (pretty sure you have to as pointed out below).

Comment: @Lundin Cortex M3 (at least) have FPU extention, so I guess you are talking about M0/M0+ ?

Comment: You should avoid magic numbers anyway.

Comment: @user2162550 M0 to M3 don't have FPU. It is optional on M4.

Comment: @Lundin ohh snap. I checked it again and you're right, good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. This is fundamental syntax and cannot be altered.

Even if it was possible, I would avoid it at all costs, as your C project would no longer be actual C, but some bizarro dialect with a *huge* difference in semantics of numeric literals; reusing code from your project, importing code from another one, or having anyone else do work on your project would be a correctness hazard.

FWIW, the missing dots can be added through a trivial regex, something like:

Search: `([^.]|^)\b([0-9]+)\b([^.]|$)`

Replace: `$1$2.0$3`

(done without lookbehind/lookahead for maximum portability)

Comment: I see. I tried some regex yesterday, managed to replace simple expressions, such as `name1^N` for `pow(name1,N)`, but when exponentiation takes longer arguments, such as (name1/name2*xyz)^N, it fails.
As for replacing numbers, I wasn't able to do so. Tried your solution, using https://regexr.com/, but it didn't seem to work either. :(

Comment: It does work if you choose the PCRE engine instead of the JS one, although it can be fixed easily to work with both by using `$` instead of ``\`` for replacement variables.

Comment: Alright! It worked as expected for the first few ones! I will test translating larger and more complex equations! Thank you!

Comment: I had to run it twice in some cases. I guess it depends on the engine, but, using the regexr.com website, on the first run for it would find for the sample `eq = (121/16);` at first `(121/`, yielding `(121.0/` and on the second run, after copying the resulting text to the sample text area, it would find `/16)` and finally replace it with `/16.0)`.
Such behavior may be because of the overlap that occurs in both strings.

Comment: @PauloSherring: yeah that's because I cheated and I didn't use lookahead/lookbehind... that can be fixed, now that I know what engine you are using. You can use `([^.]|^)\b([0-9]+)\b(?![.])` as search and `$1$2.0` as replace.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a caste: double a = (double) 1/3..

Comment: I think this is even worse. The OP wants to avoid having to append a .0 on every single constant throughout the code, adding an explicit cast would be more time consuming and the code with be cluttered.

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga: still, it is well inside correctly solving the problem that OP has – forcing the compiler to use floating point numbers instead of integers. When preprocessing the source, this would work as well as the current solution, adding a period to all suspects.